# TimerTask not executing

Tags: java, timer

I am programming a discord bot and want to run an unban at a certain time.
However, the TimerTask is not called even though the date is in the future.
If the date is in the past, the timertask calls instant.
I've tried to sout some data to look if the date is wrong but its right.

I want to call it once.

```
        System.out.println("started");
        System.out.println(date);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("called");
                user.openPrivateChannel().complete().sendMessage(
                        "**-Unban-**" +
                                "\n" +
                                "Du wurdest entbannt!"
                ).queue();
                guild.removeRoleFromMember(user.getId(), guild.getRoleById("690579286582624276")).queue();
                guild.addRoleToMember(user.getId(), guild.getRoleById("688733671104053327")).queue();
            }
        }, date);
```

Output from Console:

```
started
Fri Mar 20 17:21:55 UTC 2020
```

Hope you'll find out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Main {
    Date date = new Date();// Initialize it as per your requirement
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("called");
            //...
            timer.cancel();
        }
    };

    public void start() {
        timer.schedule(task, date);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main timer = new Main();
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to repeat it. I want to call it at the date once.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope, it fulfils your requirement.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I did it again the way you just described it, but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: @JAN - If you execute my code as it is, you will get the output, `called`. Isn't it? If yes, why don't you just copy my `TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {...` code as it is and put your remaining code after `System.out.println("called");`? Make sure that `start` is called (I've done it in `main`); otherwise, you won't get the required output.

Comment: nope i don't get called
my code:
https://hastebin.com/libujuzaqa.java

Comment: @JAN - Interesting! When I run the code at hastebin.com/libujuzaqa.java, I am getting, `called` as the output exactly after 10 seconds. Aren't you? If you want to execute the task only once, make sure to use `timer.cancel();` the way I have done. Feel free to comment in case of any issue/doubt.

Answer (score 0):

to use the timer should do the next

scheduleAtFixedRate

Example

reloj.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Reloj(), 0, 1000);

You can do the next

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication11;

import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 *
 * @author Sem-6-INGENIERIAINDU
 */
public class Reloj extends TimerTask{

    @Override
    public void run() {
      // Your code
    }

}
```

The class implements the timer
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package javaapplication11;

```
import java.util.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author Sem-6-INGENIERIAINDU
 */
public class JavaApplication11 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Timer reloj=new Timer();
      reloj.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Reloj(), 0, 1000);

    }

}
```

The result is

> run: Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo
>   Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo
>   Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo
>   Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo
>   Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo
>   Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo
>   Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo
>   Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo
>   Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo
>   Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo Corriendo
>   Corriendo Corriendo BUILD STOPPED (total time: 1 minute 10 seconds)

Comment: I dont want to repeat it. I want to call it at the date once.

Comment: you only need to put the date in hours

Comment: a day has 86.400.000 Millisecond

Comment: Timer reloj=new Timer();
      reloj.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Reloj(), 0, 86400000);